# How does CPython's interpreter know to print the result of the last expression?

Tags: python, cpython, python-internals

I've been digging around the source code to figure-out at which point the result is printed. For example:

```
>>> x = 1
>>> x + 2
3
```

The above two statements are compiled to:

```
  1           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (1)
              3 STORE_NAME               0 (x)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (None)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

and

```
  1           0 LOAD_NAME                0 (x)
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (2)
              6 BINARY_ADD
              7 RETURN_VALUE
```

The first statement doesn't print anything because `None` is the returned value. The second returns the result of the addition.

CPython's interactive loop calls [`PyRun_InteractiveOneObjectEx()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/42aa93b8ff2f7879282b06efc73a31ec7785e602/Python/pythonrun.c#L120) for each input. This [gets the AST](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/42aa93b8ff2f7879282b06efc73a31ec7785e602/Python/pythonrun.c#L236) and invokes `run_mod()` to [compile that AST to byte code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/42aa93b8ff2f7879282b06efc73a31ec7785e602/Python/pythonrun.c#L1032) and then [evaluate the result](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/42aa93b8ff2f7879282b06efc73a31ec7785e602/Python/pythonrun.c#L1035) in the virtual machine. The returned Python object that `PyRun_InteractiveOneObjectEx()` gets is simply the [top of the VM's stack](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3a9ccee0e5dbf7d67f5ab79f6095755969db117c/Python/ceval.c#L1631).

So far all of this is what I would expect. But then the returned value seems to be [thrown away](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/42aa93b8ff2f7879282b06efc73a31ec7785e602/Python/pythonrun.c#L256)! When is this printed by the REPL?

As an aside, I can see that interactive mode does change the tokenizer; it [`invokes PyOS_Readline`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/f2ddc6ac9370a1805ab1b751437df8f96f38bfcf/Parser/tokenizer.c#L934) with the `sys.ps1` prompt (`">>> "` by default). I checked for a similar change in `pythonrun.c`, but no luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are showing disassemblies of the bytecode as generated by having the code in a function.  That isn't how interactive code is compiled: it uses a special 'single' mode (3rd parameter to `compile()`, if you were doing the equivalent in Python code).  In this mode, the `POP_TOP` opcode that discards the value of each expression gets turned into a `PRINT_EXPR` instead.  The reason why `x = 1` prints nothing is that statements leave nothing on the stack that needs to be popped, so this transformation doesn't apply.

Answer (score 0):

Correct [answer from @jasonharper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50374656/478288)! For posterity, here's a deeper look of what's going on.

The above disassembly shows the results of `eval` mode:

```
>>> list(compile('x + 2', '<stdin>', 'eval').co_code)
[101, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 23, 83]
```

The opcodes can be viewed with:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.opname[101]
'LOAD_NAME'
>>> dis.opname[100]
'LOAD_CONST'
>>> dis.opname[23]
'BINARY_ADD'
>>> dis.opname[83]
'RETURN_VALUE'
```

The two numbers following the opcode represent a 16-bit operand, though only the first byte is what we need here. So this corresponds to:

```
LOAD_NAME     0
LOAD_CONST    0
BINARY_ADD
RETURN_VALUE
```

Those operands are indices to the compiled code object's variable names and constant pool, respectively.

```
>>> c = compile('x + 2', '<stdin>', 'eval')
>>> c.co_names
('x',)
>>> c.co_consts
(2,)
```

So far, this is what we have in the question. But in reality, executing Python code results in:

```
>>> list(compile('x + 2', '<stdin>', 'exec').co_code)
[101, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 23, 1, 100, 1, 0, 83]
>>> dis.opname[1]
'POP_TOP'
```

I.e., the result is discarded and a `None` is introduced as the return value.

In interactive mode, we have:

```
>>> list(compile('x + 2', '<stdin>', 'single').co_code)
[101, 0, 0, 100, 0, 0, 23, 70, 100, 1, 0, 83]
>>> dis.opname[70]
'PRINT_EXPR'
```

The result is printed (via [`sys.displayhook`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.displayhook)) and a `None` becomes the actual return value.

So the printing is introduced by the code generation phase, not by the VM.